# Nested for-loop error python

Tags: python, for-loop

I am completely new to programing. I am trying to nest what i think is a "for-loop" inside of what i think is a "for-loop". Every time i run the program i get an error: "There's an error in your program:
unexpected unindent". I honestly have no clue how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Here is the Code:

```html
import urllib2
import time

stocksToPull  = 'AAPL'
  
def pullData(stock):
    try:
        pricedata = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.google.com/finance/getprices?i=60&p=1d&f=d,o,h,l,c,v&df=cpct&q="+stock+"").read()

        pricevalues = pricedata.split()
        current_price = float(pricevalues[len(pricevalues)-1].split(",")[4]) #High

        pricevalues = pricedata.split()
        Pcurrent_price = float(pricevalues[len(pricevalues)-1].split(",")[2]) #Open

        DPCge= (current_price/Pcurrent_price)/Pcurrent_price #Daily Precent Change

        number = 0.010000000000
# This is the begging of the nested for-loop
        if stock == 'AAPL' and DPCge> number:
         for eachStock in stocksToPull:
          stocksToPull  = 'AAPL'
          pullData(eachStock)

   def pullData(stock):
           try:
                                    pricedata = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.google.com/finance/getprices?i=60&p=1d&f=d,o,h,l,c,v&df=cpct&q="+stock+"").read()

                                    pricevalues = pricedata.split()
                                    current_price = float(pricevalues[len(pricevalues)-1].split(",")[4]) #High

                                    pricevalues = pricedata.split()
                                    Pcurrent_price = float(pricevalues[len(pricevalues)-1].split(",")[2]) #Open

                                    DPCge= (current_price/Pcurrent_price)/Pcurrent_price #Daily Precent Change

                                    number = 0.010000000000

except Exception,e:
    print'main loop',str(e)

for eachStock in stocksToPull:
    pullData(eachStock)
```

Comment: If this is the exact code you are using, you need to indent `except` block to match with `try` block.

Comment: Your function is listed twice, too, unless that's what u want. Your code can probably be condensed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you have two try blocks and one except. The indentation of the except block does not align with either of the try blocks. Moreover, you have defined the same function within the given function! Your code is all over the place. Remove the inner function block and replace it with a call to the function if that is what you need and fix your try and except blocks.